# Factoring a polynomial of fourth degree with false roots: $x^4+4$

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers, partial-fractions

I want to write this polynomial in factored form:

$$x^4+4$$

The reason I want to do this is to be able to make **partial-fraction decomposition** on it to make an integrand easier to integrate. *What's the general method?*

In addition to this, I searched on how to figure out the numerators $A, B...etc$ for this decomposed fraction, *is Inverse Laplace the way to go?* Or is there another way? (which doesnt make it any more difficult).

Comment: $$x^4+4=(x^4+4x^2+4)-4x^2=(x^2+2)^2-(2x)^2=\cdots$$

Comment: Try $(x^2+2)^2-4x^2$ as the difference of two squares

Comment: @MarkBennet This is what Wolfram showed me as well. However, anywhere I search for difference of two squares, I get some examples like $a^2-b^2$ which doesn't really help me at all on how to manipulate this.

Comment: Try $a=x^2+2$ and $b=2x$

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**

$$x^4+4=(x^4\color{red}{+4x^2}+4) \color{red}{-4x^2}$$
and notice that
$$a^2-b^2=(a-b)(a+b)$$

Answer (score 3):

$x^4 + 4 = (x^2 + 2i)(x^2 - 2i)$

or without complex numbers :

$x^4 + 4 = (x^2 - 2x + 2)(x^2 + 2x + 2)$

Maybe that helps you ?

Answer (score 1):

You equate the polynomial to zero and solve the equation. In this case, you find that the roots are

$$x_n = \sqrt{2}\exp(i \pi n/2)$$

for $n = 0,1,2,3$

The partial fraction expansion will then be of the form:

$$\sum_{n=0}^3 \frac{A_n}{x-x_n}$$

where $A_n$ is the residue of the integrand at $x = x_n$.

Comment: Oh, this is nice. Where can I read about that form?

Comment: But I think the OP wants to avoid complex numbers.
This is usually the case for integrals not ?

Comment: And also, am I right if I let $x^4 + 4 = (x^2+2i)(x^2-2i) = \frac{A}{x^2+2i} + \frac{A^*}{x^2-2i}$?

Comment: Some time ago I explained this method here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/982391/integral-of-rational-function-with-higher-degree-in-numerator/982808#982808